# Chamfered Rectangle and Minimum Text Height

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

*pgf/tikz*: I am trying to create a hexagon with a fixed height . Using the chamfered Rectangle. I can turn the rectangle into a hexagon, but when I try to apply the minimum height option it seems to interfere with setting the xsep.

Does anyone know a way around this?

This is the macro I'm trying to make.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\Task}[2]{|[chamfered rectangle, chamfered rectangle angle=50, thick, draw, text centered, text width=1.5cm, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.3cm, chamfered rectangle xsep=5cm, scale=0.5](#1)|{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}         
        \matrix (grlplay) [matrix of nodes, row sep = 0mm] %grlFlow-row-column
        {   
            &\Task{label}{name} &   \\
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Please post a full but minimal example for your question. Also, your command doesn't output anything because this: `{|[` is not a proper Tikz command. Maybe you meant `{\node[`?

Comment: @Alenanno done. The { | [ is a valid command. Using matrix means you do not need to constantly write node.

Comment: @Zarko hmmm I was under the impression that regular polygon creates one with equal sides? I may be mistaken. I want more of a rectangle with the angled edges. I know I could apply scaling to squish the polygon to the height I'm after, but then the points become over exaggerated.

Comment: Only if we know it's supposed to go in a matrix.

Comment: @Alenanno I admit I should have included a complete example. However, flat out assuming it was incorrect was still a mistake. By the same strand I could argue \node  is invalid because you didn't say I had to put it in tikz environment.

Comment: Try to omit `chamfered rectangle xsep=3cm`. Without it the chamfer part of node stay equal.

Comment: What I meant is that we are not supposed to know what you want to do or what you're trying to do unless you say it. And I'm not sure your approach is the most appropriate either.

Comment: @Zarko If I omit that I get an octagon, which is what I currently have. As I said, the problem is that the minimum height is cancelling out the xsep. If I remove minimum height the xsep option starts working again but the node is the incorrect height.

Comment: ok, now I see, what you like to obtain. This is more easy to obtain by shape `signal`.

Comment: @Alenanno I apologise if I took your comment the wrong way. What approach would you recommend taking?

Comment: No worries! I am still not sure what you're trying to do, but I suppose you want a matrix of nodes where each "cell" is a chamfered rectangle?

Comment: @Zarko I didnt think of that.... but it is not letting me select an answer. nm, it was only a comment at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you like to have as final shape form, than this is easier to obtain by `signal` shape than with `chamfered rectangle`. It provide hexagon independent from desired text height:

[image]

For above picture I expand your matrix and change the way to define its cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,shapes.symbols}

% for show only figure
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
task/.style = {signal, draw, thick, 
               signal to=west and east,
               text width=22mm, minimum height=9mm, align=center}
                            ]
\matrix (grlplay) [matrix of nodes, row sep = 1mm] %grlFlow-row-column
{
left   &   \node[task] {name}; &  right \\
left   &   \node[task] {name}; &  right \\
};
%\draw[red,->] (grlplay-1-1) -- (grlplay-1-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```